# How to map an array of objects and fetch network data for each in JS?

Tags: javascript, axios, es6-promise

I am making apps in React Native. I have to fetch an array of data of categories from a URL and then for each category I have to fetch assets from their respective URLs.

My data is stored in the following format:

From the `mainURL`:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Home",
  "type": "",
  "url": "",
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "id": 92,
      "name": "Documentary",
      "type": "JTV_LEAF",
      "url": "yyy",
    }
  ]
}
```

From each category URL,

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Inception",
    "type": "vod"
  }
]
```

How do I fetch data for each category using `map` and `reduce` and `axios`?

---

This is what I have written so far. I am getting `undefined` at the end.

```
export const fetchNavigationFeed = (navUrl, subId) => {
  return dispatch => {
    const url = navUrl
      .replace("__JTV__SUBSCRIBER__ID__", subId);
    dispatch({ type:FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED });
    return axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        let categories = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.subCategories.length; i++) {
            var cat = response.data.subCategories[i];
            var category = new Category(cat);
            categories.push(category);
        }
        console.log(categories);
        let promises = [];
        categories.map(category => {
          let request = axios.get(category.url)
            .then(assetsJson => {
              let assets = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < assetsJson.data.length; i++) {
                  var ass = assetsJson.data[i];
                  var asset = new Asset(ass);
                  assets.push(asset);
              }
              category.assets = assets;
            });
          promises.push(request);
        });
        axios.all(promises)
          .then(axios.spread(...args) => {
            console.log(args);
          });
        return categories;
      })
      .then(categories => {
        // console.log(categories);
        dispatch({ type:FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS, payload:categories });
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Since you use arrow functions with {} instead of implicit returns, I would expect that you have to 1) return the fetch chain: `return fetch( category.url)` and 2) return the category after assigning the assets to it: `.then((assets) => { category.assets = assets; return category });` so that the array given to Promise.all actually contains the promises for these categories.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal For every category, there is a URL which contains a list of assets. I want to fetch them and add them as a field in each category.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you already have written, what does not work as expected?

Comment: @Bergi The result does not give the list of categories but some promise object.

Comment: @khateeb Which result exactly? Surely `args` or `categories` are no promise object. Also did you fix the missing `return`s that Shilly mentioned yet?

Comment: @Bergi I am a complete novice to JS and Promises and Axios. I couldn't understand what Shilly was saying.

The final result will be a list of categories and inside each category there should be a list of assets which are fetched from the url in the category object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working example and `jest` test:

---

code.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED = 'FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED';
export const FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS';

class Category {
  constructor(json) {
    this.id = json.id;
    this.name = json.name;
    this.url = json.url;
  }
}

class Asset {
  constructor(json) {
    this.id = json.id;
    this.title = json.title;
  }
}

export const fetchNavigationFeed = (navUrl, subId) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED });

    const url = navUrl
      .replace('__JTV__SUBSCRIBER__ID__', subId);
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const categories = [];
    const promises = [];
    response.data.subCategories.forEach((subCategory) => {
      const category = new Category(subCategory);
      categories.push(category);
      const promise = axios.get(category.url).then((subResponse) => {
        category.assets = [];
        subResponse.data.forEach((asset) => {
          category.assets.push(new Asset(asset));
        });
      });
      promises.push(promise);
    });
    // wait for all the promises simultaneously
    await Promise.all(promises);

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS, payload: categories });
  }
}
```

---

code.test.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {
  fetchNavigationFeed,
  FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED,
  FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS
} from './code';

const getMock = jest.spyOn(axios, 'get');
getMock.mockImplementation((url) => {
  switch (url) {
    case 'mainUrl-mySubId':
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "home",
          "subCategories": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "sub1",
              "url": "sub1Url",
            },
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "sub2",
              "url": "sub2Url",
            }
          ]
        }
      });
    case 'sub1Url':
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "asset1"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "asset2"
          }
        ]
      });
    case 'sub2Url':
      return Promise.resolve({
        data: [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "asset3"
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "asset4"
          }
        ]
      });
  }
});


test('getData', async () => {
  const asyncDispatch = fetchNavigationFeed('mainUrl-__JTV__SUBSCRIBER__ID__', 'mySubId');
  const dispatch = jest.fn();
  await asyncDispatch(dispatch);
  expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  const firstCallArgs = dispatch.mock.calls[0];
  expect(firstCallArgs).toEqual([{
    type: FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED
  }]);
  const secondCallArgs = dispatch.mock.calls[1];
  expect(secondCallArgs).toEqual([{
    type: FETCH_NAVIGATION_FEED_SUCCESS,
    payload: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'sub1',
        url: 'sub1Url',
        assets: [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "asset1"
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "asset2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'sub2',
        url: 'sub2Url',
        assets: [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "asset3"
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "asset4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]);
});
```

Note: you can use `axios.all()` but according to [this thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042) it uses `Promise.all()` under the hood anyway.

Comment: @khateeb let me know if this covers what you need and if you have any questions about the implementation

Comment: I am getting an error: `await is a reserved keyword`. I have updated my sample code. Where do I put the `async` keyowrd? I am using `react-native`, `redux` and `redux-thunk`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot! I just started JS and React a week back and I was really stuck here! The `async` comes before the first `dispatch`.

Comment: SO says I can award you the bounty after 22 hours.

Comment: @khateeb just saw your comments I was almost done with updating the sample code so I just finished and posted it here, glad it's working!

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
fetch(url)
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then(async (data) => {
    const categories = data.subCategories
             .map(category => new Category(category.id, category.name, category.type, category.url))

    for(category of categories) {
       let assets = await fetch(category.url).then(rsp => rsp.json())
       assets = assets.map(asset => Asset(assets.id, assets.title, assets.type, ass.thumbnail));
       category.assets = assets;
    }

    return categories
 }).then(categoriesWithAssets => {/*done*/})
```

Comment: I am getting a `SyntaxError: await is a reserved word`. Is there any way to this using the `axios` library?

Comment: Why would you mix in so many `then` calls if you were using `async`/`await`?